# how do I access `error` field from `onComplete` or `data` field from `onError` in Apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

We have a graphql mutation call that can possibly return a response with both the `errors` field and `data` field:

```
{
 "data": // data,
 "errors": // errors,
}
```

without setting `errorPolicy: all` to the `useMutation` hook, `onCompleted` will fire only if there is no `errors` present in the response and `onError` will fire only if there is `errors` present in the response. However, the issue I am facing is that, `onComplete` handler doesn’t have access to the `errors` field when it is present in the response and `onError` handler doesn’t have access to the `data` field in the response either.

Once I set `errorPolicy: all` to the `useMutation` hook, `onComplete` will always fire even when the `errors` field is present in the response, but still it doesn't have access to `errors` from the `onComplete` handler. The `onError` handler will never fire even when the `errors` field is present in the response. We can only get the `errors` from the `result` object returned by `useMutation`. But I wonder if there is a better, more elegant way to handle this within the respective handlers (i.e. `onCompleted` and `onError`)